# Pyspark pipelineModel.transform error 'Field "cut_catVec" does not exist.\nAvailable fields

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to run MLlip in Pyspark to predict price and I'm using dataframe that have this schema:

```
[('cut', 'string'),
 ('color', 'string'),
 ('clarity', 'string'),
 ('carat', 'double'),
 ('table', 'int'),
 ('x', 'double'),
 ('y', 'double'),
 ('z', 'double'),
 ('price', 'int')]
```

so after identifying categorical and numerical columns:

```
`categ_col= ['cut', 'color' ,'clarity']
num_col= ['carat','table', 'x', 'y', 'z']``
```

In below script I:

- First using StringIndexer to convert string/text values into numerical values followed by OneHotEncoderEstimator
- Spark MLLibto convert each Stringindexed or transformed values into One Hot Encoded values.
- VectorAssembler is being used to assemble all the features into one vector from multiple columns that contain type double
- Also appending every step of the process in a stages array

  ```
  `from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, OneHotEncoderEstimator, 
  VectorAssembler
  stages = []
  for catcol in categ_col:
     stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol = catcol, outputCol =                         catcol + 'Index')
   OHencoder = OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCols=[stringIndexer.getOutputCol()], outputCols=[catcol + "_catVec"])
  stages += [stringIndexer, OHencoder]
  assemblerInputs = [c + "_catVec" for c in categ_col] + num_col
  Vectassembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=assemblerInputs,                                 outputCol="features")
  stages += [Vectassembler]`
  ```

``

when I went to next step:

```
    `from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
    cols = mllipdf.columns
    pipeline = Pipeline(stages = stages)
    pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(mllipdf)
    mllipdf = pipelineModel.transform(mllipdf)
    selectedCols = ['features']+cols
    mllipdf = mllipdf.select(selectedCols)
    pd.DataFrame(mllipdf.take(5), columns=mllipdf.columns)`
```

I got an error on 
cod
`mllipdf = pipelineModel.transform(mllipdf)" line saying "IllegalArgumentException: 'Field "cut_catVec" does not exist.\nAvailable fields: cut, color, clarity, carat, table, x, y, z, price, clarityIndex, clarity_catVec'`

not sure what happens here

Comment: move `stages += [stringIndexer, OHencoder]` into the `for` loop

Comment: Ya, this fixed it, Thanks